# WPF TAB cycle between DataGrids

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

In WPF `DataGrid`'s default TAB navigation cycles cells/rows. My DataGrids are both readonly and their selection unit is row, so this default behaviour makes no sense. How can I cycle between `DataGrids` instead?
The following sample *somewhat* works, but needs mouse interaction before secondary DataGrids are capable of receiving focus on <kbd>TAB</kbd> and accept arrow keys to cycle selected rows:

```
<Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid Name="MasterDG" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="10"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Once" 
              IsTabStop="True" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"
              TabIndex="1">            
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Details, ElementName=MasterDG}" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="10"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Once"
              IsTabStop="True" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"
              TabIndex="2"/>
</Grid>
```

in addition is it is awefully complicated:

1. Define `TabNavigation` on parent
2. Set `IsTabStop = false` on every cell
3. Set `IsTabStop = true` on every DataGrid
4. Set `FocusManager.IsFocusScope`s
5. Overwrite default `TabNavigation`on every DataGrid

How to fix the sample so that it correctly cycles between the two DataGrids?

---

Codebehind used in sample:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class Master
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Detail> Details { get; set; }
    }
    public class Detail
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
    public List<Master> Items => new List<Master>()
    {
        new Master() {
            Value = 1,
            Details = new List<Detail>() { new Detail() { Value = 11 }, new Detail() { Value = 12 }, new Detail() { Value = 13 }, }
        },
        new Master() {
            Value = 2,
            Details = new List<Detail>() { new Detail() { Value = 24 }, new Detail() { Value = 25 }, new Detail() { Value = 26 }, }
        },
        new Master() {
            Value = 3,
            Details = new List<Detail>() { new Detail() { Value = 37 }, new Detail() { Value = 18 }, new Detail() { Value = 19 }, }
        },
    };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"My DataGrids are both readonly and their selection unit is row"* - you can use `ListView` instead.

Comment: @Sinatr interesting option, thanks for the suggestion. If I started new project from the scratch I would probably explore it more, alas there is lot of work and customization and GUI aspects tied to DataGrids at this point, such massive refactoring is not feasible at this point, I am afraid.